# Qt, creating very custom table

Tags: c++, qt, tabular

[image]

Hello! I wonder if there is a way of making such kind of table with combined cells using Qt.

Any advices?

Comment: very, very hard, but possible. All your rows heights seem to be a multiple of some height. You can simulate the larger heights by joining together multiple rows. Or write your own `View` or even entire `QWidget`.

Comment: In which context are you referring? QTextDocument? QTableView?

Comment: Try experimenting with `QTreeView` which is also suitable for displaying table data. Because your image is a tree. Or if you want arbitrary cells combined, maybe update the image.

Comment: Try playing around with `QTableView::setSpan()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [RobbieE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2420653/robbiee) said in comments `QTableView::setSpan()` function does this job very well!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QGridLayout`, add `QFrame`s and set the `rowSpan` and `columnSpan` of each item to group cells.
You will have to come up with your own controller, though, for applying data to the cells.

[image]